# week day week-percent from time-series

Tags: r, time-series, tapply

I have some daily time-series data that i need to extract the 'week day percent' relative to the week mean. For example, if the first week has `mean = 100` and the *Sunday* value for this week is 20, then sunday becomes 0.2.

Here's some random data:

```
set.seed(0)
y = rnorm(1705)
date = seq(as.Date('2008-01-01'), by = 'day', length = length(y))
data.df = data.frame(y, date)
```

I need a new column called `pecent`, which is the value explained above. I tried to add some
columns then use `tapply`, but failed. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a `week` variable using `format`. Then use `ddply` and `transform`.

```
library(plyr)
data.df$week <- format(data.df$date,'%W %Y') #week begins with Monday
data.df <- ddply(data.df,~week,transform,percent=y/mean(y))
head(data.df)

           y       date    week    percent
1  1.2629543 2008-01-01 00 2008  3.1395415
2 -0.3262334 2008-01-02 00 2008 -0.8109741
3  1.3297993 2008-01-03 00 2008  3.3057095
4  1.2724293 2008-01-04 00 2008  3.1630952
5  0.4146414 2008-01-05 00 2008  1.0307451
6 -1.5399500 2008-01-06 00 2008 -3.8281172
```

Note that week 00 usually is not a full week as is the last week of the year. Merge last and first weeks of subsequent years if that matters.

Comment: To avoid the incomplete weeks at the begining and the end of each year,
you can use the first day of the week to identify the week,
instead of the week number: `date - as.numeric(format(date,"%u")) + 1`.